# Retrieving Two Values from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Can someone tell me how I can combine the two SQL statements that count the number of messages and number of unread messages? Its ineffecient two have two statements but I don't know what to search for to get the answer im looking for. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetMessages (
  @username nchar(12),
  @isCount bit,
  @message_count int OUTPUT,
  @unread_message_count int OUTPUT
) AS

IF @isCount = 1
BEGIN
  SET @message_count = 
  (
    SELECT        COUNT(*)
    FROM          messages
    WHERE         usernameTo = @username
  )

  SET @unread_message_count =
  (
    SELECT        COUNT(*)
    FROM          messages
    WHERE         usernameTo = @username AND message_read = 1
  )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT        *
  FROM          messages
  WHERE         usernameTo = @username
END
```

Comment: This procedure returns wildly different results based on the value of one parameter. This should be two procedures, not one. I'm scared about the rest of this app's design if this is how its procedures are built.

Comment: SQL isn't my forte and its a favor for a friends site. No need for elegance.

Comment: i have to agree with Welbog 110%. This is a VERY bad design! this will come to bite you later on.

Comment: This isn't about elegance, it's about readability, maintainability, and best practices. Even if this is a short side project, you should still do it properly for two very good reasons. 1) It's good practice for the real deal. 2) The short side projects rarely end there; They usually keep going, building up, and eventually become a big mess when you don't start with the right foundation.

Comment: theres elegance in bad design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll want this to be split into two stored procedures. If you are ever using a bit to determine which chunk of code to execute, you're probably trying to put too much into one stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetMessageCount (
  @username nchar(12),
  @message_count int OUTPUT,
  @unread_message_count int OUTPUT
) AS

SELECT
    @message_count = SUM(CASE WHEN message_read = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    @unread_message_count = SUM(CASE WHEN message_read <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM messages
WHERE usernameTo = @username

GO
```

You could do something like this for the stored procdure that will get all messages for a specific user. You don't want to use "Select *", here. You should always list the specific columns you need. I listed a few example columns.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetMessagesByUser (
    @username nchar(12)
) AS

  SELECT
      MessageID,
      MessageSubject,
      MessageContent,
      MessageFromUser,
      MessageCreatedDate
  FROM          messages
  WHERE         usernameTo = @username

GO
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. There are only 5 columns and I need them all. Thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: IMHO there's no need for a stored procedure at all. All you're doing is wrapping a single query...

Comment: Some people like to make sure that all SQL calls are in SPs. I'm not convinced that that's necessary, but it is certainly mandatory at many workplaces. If you need to use one, you can do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) as TotalCount, 
    count(case when message_read = 1 then 1 else null end) as ReadMessageCount, 
    count(case when message_read <> 1 then 1 else null end) as UnreadMessageCount
from messages
where usernameTo = 'jsmith'
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the SQL you're using, but, for instance, in `PostgreSQL` it would be like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS messages,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN message_read=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) AS unreads,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN message_read=1 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) AS reads
FROM messages WHERE usernameTo='someone';
```

That should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_messages,      
       SUM(CASE WHEN message_read=1 THEN 1 END) as read, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN message_read=0 THEN 1 END) as unread
FROM mesages WHERE usernameTo='username';
```